# Rectangle with rounded sides

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

How can I code these rectangles with rounded corenrs using CSS/SVG/etc. pictures :

[image]

I tried coding this with border-radius, but with border-radius horizontal or vertical sides are straight.

And how I can code lower ridge of rounded rectangles?

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: Create paths using bezier curves.

Comment: Simply fire-up an SVG editor, draw your shape and that's it, done.

Comment: I just hope your question doesn't get closed until I'm done writing the code for that shape.

Comment: **how can this answer be more focused?** that's just beyond me, OP is asking a VERY focused question with precise description of what they try to achieve in what technology manner. Please "alessandro, web-tiki, Vitorino fernandes, Harry, Gildas.Tambo." don't subjectively close questions that actually could be helpful to the whole community .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `svg`'s bezier curves.

[image]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 4em 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #FFEFE3;
  font-size: 13.1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="shape" width="400" height="100%" viewBox="-1 -1 401 158" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="#FFAC61" d="M0 75 c1 -30 4 -60 30 -65 q200 -20 343 0 c20 6 24 40 25 65 c0 25 -6 57 -27 65 c-90 17 -210 6 -240 7 c-10 -1 -20 0 -40 8 c-7 0 -10 -1 -15 -8 c-4 -4 -20 -6 -50 -7 c-30 -10 -23 -57 -27.5 -73" />
  </svg>
  <div class="content">The English Wikipedia is the English-language edition of the free online encyclopedia Wikipedia.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to generate this bezier curves?

Comment: @user3266599 if you don't know how to do that from the top of your head or by alter/try - the easiest way is probably to create this in a SVG editor - many online SVG editors are able to do that and I believe even the cross-platform Boxy :)